# Using Openssl S_server to test chrome HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

I write a HTTPS Server by Openssl. Using Chrome to connect the server, It has ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. But Using Firefox to connect the server,It work fine. 
I follow the sites http://blog.jorisvisscher.com/2015/07/22/create-a-simple-https-server-with-openssl-s_server/
`openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 44330 -www`
The result is the same.
How can I solve it!
Thanks for reading this Q!

Answer (score 0):

Your chrome probably refused the connection because it was unsecure (here Firefox Developer Edition also refused). By default, openssl uses weak DH parameters, and unsupported protocols (like SSLv3), you should add additional options to secure your server.

First, generate stronger DH params:

```
openssl dhparam -out dhparam.pem 2048
```

Use at least 2048, the bigger, the better (I usually use 4096). Then run your server with this command instead:

```
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -accept 44330 \
  -no_ssl3 -dhparam dhparam.pem -www
```

Be aware that SSLv2 is also in ways of being deprecated (PCI compliance will fail for SSLv2 by the middle of this year), and there are also several ciphers that are unsecure.

If you'd like a really strong dhparam, consider installing a service for generating more entropy, like haveged (before generating dhparams):

```
apt-get install haveged
```